# How to create a 'Like' + 'In' query in SQL Server (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm looking a way to create a query that includes the functionality of both: 'Like' and 'In' keywords together. So with this I'll be able to make a search of multiple sub-strings in one sentence instead of creating multiple consults:

i.e:

Instead of this:

```
select * from MyTable where ColumnName like'%substring1%'
select * from MyTable where ColumnName like'%substring2%'
select * from MyTable where ColumnName like '%substring3%'
```

I want to do something like this:

```
select * from MyTable where ColumnName in ('%substring1%','%substring2%','%substring3%')
```

Just to clarify: the wild card (%) is not allowed or it doesn't work together with the "in" keyword so it forces me to look for full strings instead of substrings.

Any idea or approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only approach I can think of is the following:

```
select * from MyTable where ColumnName like '%substring1%' or ColumnName like '%substring2%' or ColumnName like '%substring3%'
```

If you have additional conditions, just group it.

```
select * from MyTable where (ColumnName like '%substring1%' or ColumnName like '%substring2%' or ColumnName like '%substring3%') and AnotherColumn='string'
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid to type the column name again, but I think the 'or' keyword is doing all the trick, THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Pre-populate a temp table with the terms you want to search (or table variable, CTE, or whatever). Then join but use `like` instead of an equalty operator.

```
select *
from myTable a
inner join #terms b
   on a.myField like '%' + b.term + '%'
```

Comment: Nice idea. If you want to do it inline then use a table constructor like this: `select t.* from myTable t join (values ('substring1'),('substring2')) terms(sub) on a.myField like '%'+sub+'%'`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is pass a delimited string

**Example**

```
Declare @Search varchar(max) = 'John,Cappelletti,Some Other Value'

Select Distinct A.*
 From  MyTable  A
 Join  (
         Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
         From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Search,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
         Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
        ) B on charindex(RetVal,ColumnName)>0
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use or operator;

```
SELECT ColumnName 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%substring1%' OR ColumnName LIKE '%substring2%' OR ColumnName LIKE '%substring3%'
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid to type the column name again, but I think the 'or' keyword is doing all the trick, THANKS!